# Por que x += y soma os valores em uma iteração?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lógica

Não estou entendendo o porquê desse código `r += v` somar os valores. Gostaria que alguém me explicasse o porquê do output deste código:

```r
for c in range (0, 10):
    v = int(input("numero: "))
    r += v
print(f"resultado: {r}")
```

Comment: O título estava correto. quando se trata de uma pergunta o "por que" é separado.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`r += v` não soma valores em uma iteração. É uma expressão que acumula valor. Não importa onde foi usada. Se estiver dentro de uma interação então o acúmulo é feito ali dentro.

O operador `+=` é chamado de composto, porque ele faz duas coisas. Ele realiza uma soma e uma atribuição de valor, ao mesmo tempo. Esse código é o mesmo que escrever:

```
r = r + v
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Operator/Compound2.py).

Então está pegando o valor atual de `r` e somando com o valor atual de `v`. E na mesma operação guardando o resultado dessa soma em `r`, o que portanto muda seu valor e, nesse código usado, na próxima iteração será esse novo valor considerado para somar em `r`.

O algoritmo é de acumulação, o operador só é um facilitador para dar essa semântica (em algumas linguagens no passado era usado para otimização, mas hoje em dia tem linguagem que não otimiza mesmo usando a sintaxe composta e tem linguagem que otimiza mesmo não usa essa sintaxe).

Comment: Tirou doce da boca de criança! A criança era eu. :-) enfim só me restou o +1